# Any representable moduli problem of elliptic curves is rigid

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, moduli-space

**EDIT**: As I now tried to provide an answer to this problem, I would appreciate any proof verification of my reasoning. Thank you very much!

In Katz and Mazur's book (available [here](http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/AWS/Files/KatzMazurArithmeticModuli.pdf), page 109, page 60 in the pdf), it is stated as an obvious statement that any representable moduli problem is rigid. Actually, being new to these notions, I fail to see how one can show this. Let me sum up the situation.

We consider the category $(\textbf{Ell})$ of elliptic curves over a base (maps are cartesian squares of elliptic curves). Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a moduli problem for elliptic curves (that is a contravariant functor from $(\textbf{Ell})$ to $(\textbf{Set})$). Assume that $\mathcal{P}$ is representable: there exists an elliptic curve $\mathbb{E}/\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P})$ together with a functorial isomorphism $$\mathcal{P}(E/S)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_{(\textbf{Ell})}(E/S,\mathbb{E}/\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P}))$$ 
for any object $E/S$ of $(\textbf{Ell})$.

The statement we need to prove is the following.

> Let $E/S$ be an object of $(\textbf{Ell})$ given with an element $a\in \mathcal{P}(E/S)$. Let $\epsilon:E/S\rightarrow E/S$ be an automorphism. By functoriality, it induces a map $\mathcal{P}(E/S) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(E/S)$. Assume that $a$ is a fixed point of this map. Then, $\epsilon$ is the identity.

This statement is said to be explicitly visible from the description of representable problems. Thus I feel like the proof should be quite straightforward, but I fail to see the point. Actually, I may not understand to what extent "to be representable" is a powerful statement in this context. Could somebody please clarify this point to me? I am thankful in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out a way to show it, however I am pretty unsure about this resolution. Any feedback would be gladly appreciated.

Assume that $\mathcal{P}$ is represented by a universal elliptic curve $\mathbb{E}/\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P})$ together with a universal element $a_0\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{E}/\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P}))$. This universal element is induced by the identity morphism on the universal elliptic curve.

Then, to give an element $a\in \mathcal{P}(E/S)$ is the same as to give a morphism $E/S\rightarrow \mathbb{E}/\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P})$ in $(\textbf{Ell})$ such that the image of $a_0$ by the induced map $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{E}/\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P}))\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(E/S)$ is precisely $a$. That is the data of a morphism $\phi: S\rightarrow \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P})$ and an isomorphism $\iota: E\xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb{E}\times_{\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P})}S$ of elliptic curves over $S$, such that the pullback of $a_0$ is $a$.

Now, $\operatorname{Aut(E/S)}$ acts on $\mathcal{P}(E/S)$ by keeping $\phi$ as it is and by composing $\iota$ on the right. To say that an automorphism $\epsilon$ has a fixed point means that $\iota\circ\epsilon=\iota$ as isomorphisms of elliptic curves $E\xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb{E}\times_{\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{P})}S$ over $S$.

Thus, $\iota(\epsilon-1)=0$. Because $\iota$ is an isomorphism, $\operatorname{deg}(\iota)\not = 0$, so necessarily $\operatorname{deg}(\epsilon -1)=0$, that is $\epsilon - 1=0$.

Comment: Dear Suzet, I think you can just simplify the $i$ in your equation $i\circ\epsilon= i$ to obtain the result. Imho a simpler way to show the above is using the explicit description (4.3.5) which amounts to explaining the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(E/S)$ on the set of homs and then applying the description. (In essence the same thing).